# Build a sub theme under acquia Marina in drupal

Tags: theming

I used the Acquia Marina theme to built a new sub theme. i had downloaded the fusion theme and Skinr module. now how can i proceed for the next step ? Is there any good tutorial site to help in this issues. I am using now drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to accomplish? Once you decide what changes you want to make to the base theme use Inspect Element in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to look at how whatever you want to change is styled.

If you have Cache CSS turned off you can usually see the exact file and line number of the CSS file you want to change. From there its just a matter of creating or editing the CSS in the subtheme so it contains the changes you want to make.

Acquia Marina is a subtheme of Fusion, so you should look for help theming Fusion. See [Fusion handbook - for Acquia Marina 3.x](http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/support/documentation).